# Exception in Access to JSONserialization with NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have a data from API Rest. I convert it to a `NSArray` with serialization and convert this to Dictionary. But I can't access to the pairs values (below).

1. My first step:

   ```
   NSArray *arrayDiccionario = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data _
   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&errorSerializacion];
   ```
2. My second step:

   ```
   NSMutableArray *arrayMisObjetos = [NSMutableArray new];
   ```
3. My thrid step:

   ```
   for(NSDictionary *diccionario in arrayDiccionario)
   { 
       _eventId = [ [ diccionario objectForKey:@"id" ] intValue ]; 
       _nameEvent = [  diccionario objectForKey:@"nameEvent"   ];    
   }
   ```

   *In this step I have an exception.*

   > ```
   > diccionario have 0 elements and I don´t have access to any object with Keys
   > ```

What's wrong?

Sorry for my english.

```
---- arrayDiccionario Information ----
--------------------------------------
 [0]    (null) @"listEvents" : @"10 elements" 
 key    __NSCFString    *    @"listEvents" 
 value  __NSArrayM      *    @"10 elements" 
 [0]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [0]    (null) @"id" : (long)65 
 [1]    (null) @"nameEvent" : @"Open Malaga" 
 [1]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [2]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [3]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [4]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [5]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [6]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [7]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [8]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs 
 [9]    __NSDictionaryM *    2 key/value pairs
```

Comment: I updated ordered list and code formatting.  If this is incorrect, please apply correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

what your json？show your json first
for(NSDictionary *diccionario in arrayDiccionario) your arrayDictionay is not a array。is a dictionay。you can not use for(NSDictionary *diccionario in arrayDiccionary)